# offset parameter of curand_init

Tags: cuda

I have a problem in understanding the offset parameter of `curand_init`.

The `cuRAND` guide says:

> The offset parameter is used to skip ahead in the sequence. If offset = 100, the
>   first random number generated will be the 100th in the sequence. This allows
>   multiple runs of the same program to continue generating results from the same
>   sequence without overlap.

This seems to be the skipahead concept illustrated in

```
T. Bradley, J. du Toit, R. Tong, M. Giles, P. Woodhams, "Parallelization Techniques for Random Number Generators", GPU Computing Gems, Emerald Edition.
```

Consider the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <curand.h>
#include <curand_kernel.h>

#define BLOCKSIZE 256

/**********/
/* iDivUp */
/**********/
int iDivUp(int a, int b){ return ((a % b) != 0) ? (a / b + 1) : (a / b); }

/***********************/
/* CUDA ERROR CHECKING */
/***********************/
#define gpuErrchk(ans) { gpuAssert((ans), __FILE__, __LINE__); }
inline void gpuAssert(cudaError_t code, char *file, int line, bool abort=true)
{
    if (code != cudaSuccess) 
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"GPUassert: %s %s %d\n", cudaGetErrorString(code), file, line); 
        if (abort) exit(code);
    }
}

/********************************************************/
/* KERNEL FUNCTION FOR TESTING RANDOM NUMBER GENERATION */
/********************************************************/
__global__ void testrand1(unsigned long seed, float *a, int N){
    int idx = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
    curandState state;
    if (idx < N) {
        curand_init(seed, idx, 0, &state);
        a[idx] = curand_uniform(&state);
    }
}

/********/
/* MAIN */
/********/
int main() {

    const int N = 10;

    float *h_a  = (float*)malloc(N*sizeof(float));
    float *d_a; gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc((void**)&d_a, N*sizeof(float)));

    testrand1<<<iDivUp(N, BLOCKSIZE), BLOCKSIZE>>>(1234, d_a, N);
    gpuErrchk(cudaPeekAtLastError());
    gpuErrchk(cudaDeviceSynchronize());

    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(h_a, d_a, N*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));

    for (int i=0; i<N; i++) printf("%i %f\n", i, h_a[i]);

    getchar();
}
```

A run to this code generates:

```
0 0.145468
1 0.820181
2 0.550399
3 0.294830
4 0.914733
5 0.868979
6 0.321921
7 0.782857
8 0.011302
9 0.285450
```

Now, if I use

```
curand_init(seed, idx+2, 0, &state);
```

I receive:

```
0 0.550399
1 0.294830
2 0.914733
3 0.868979
4 0.321921
5 0.782857
6 0.011302
7 0.285450
8 0.781606
9 0.233840
```

which means that the generated sequence starts from the third element of the Random Number Generator (RNG) sequence associated to `seed = 1234`. According to the definition in the `cuRAND` guide, I would then say that

```
curand_init(seed, idx+2, 0, &state);
```

should be equivalent to

```
curand_init(seed, idx, 2, &state);
```

Unfortunately, if I use the above line, I receive:

```
0 0.870710
1 0.511765
2 0.782640
3 0.620706
4 0.554513
5 0.214082
6 0.118647
7 0.993959
8 0.104572
9 0.231619
```

different from the above one.

On page `11` of the same guide, when discussing `curand_init()`, it is written:

> The state set up will be the state after `2^67 # sequence + offset` calls to `curand()` from the seed state.

which I interpret as `offset` offsets within one of `2^67` available sequences associated to a specific seed.

Anyone helps me understanding the usage of the `offset` parameter in `curand_init`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
curand_init(seed, idx+2, 0, &state);
```

should *not* be equivalent to:

```
curand_init(seed, idx, 2, &state);
```

because [sequences generated with the same seed and different sequence numbers will not have statistically correlated values](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/curand/device-api-overview.html#pseudorandom-sequences).   Note that there is no additional qualification of this statement based on the offset parameter.

The overall sequence generated has a period greater than 2^190.  Within this overall sequence there are subsequences that are identified by the 2nd parameter of the `curand_init` call.  These subsequences are independent from each other (and not statistically correlated).  These subsequences are approximately 2^67 numbers apart in the overall sequence.  The offset parameter (3rd parameter) selects the starting position within this subsequence.  Since the offset parameter cannot be larger than 2^67, it's not possible to use the offset parameter by itself to cause generated numbers to overlap.

However there is a `skipahead_sequence` [function](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/curand/device-api-overview.html#skip-ahead) provided which can allow us to do this, if we choose.  Consider the following modification to your code and sample run:

```
$ cat t557.cu
#include <stdio.h>
#include <curand.h>
#include <curand_kernel.h>

#define BLOCKSIZE 256

/**********/
/* iDivUp */
/**********/
int iDivUp(int a, int b){ return ((a % b) != 0) ? (a / b + 1) : (a / b); }

/***********************/
/* CUDA ERROR CHECKING */
/***********************/
#define gpuErrchk(ans) { gpuAssert((ans), __FILE__, __LINE__); }
inline void gpuAssert(cudaError_t code, char *file, int line, bool abort=true)
{
    if (code != cudaSuccess)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"GPUassert: %s %s %d\n", cudaGetErrorString(code), file, line);
        if (abort) exit(code);
    }
}

/********************************************************/
/* KERNEL FUNCTION FOR TESTING RANDOM NUMBER GENERATION */
/********************************************************/
__global__ void testrand1(unsigned long seed, float *a, int N){
    int idx = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
    curandState state;
    if (idx < N) {
        curand_init(seed, idx, 0, &state);
        a[(idx*2)] = curand_uniform(&state);
        if(idx%2)
          skipahead_sequence(1, &state);
        a[(idx*2)+1] = curand_uniform(&state);

    }
}

/********/
/* MAIN */
/********/
int main() {

    const int N = 10;

    float *h_a  = (float*)malloc(2*N*sizeof(float));
    float *d_a; gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc((void**)&d_a, 2*N*sizeof(float)));

    testrand1<<<iDivUp(N, BLOCKSIZE), BLOCKSIZE>>>(1234, d_a, N);
    gpuErrchk(cudaPeekAtLastError());
    gpuErrchk(cudaDeviceSynchronize());

    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(h_a, d_a, 2*N*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));

    for (int i=0; i<2*N; i++) printf("%i %f\n", i, h_a[i]);

}
$ nvcc -arch=sm_20 -o t557 t557.cu
$ ./t557
0 0.145468
1 0.434899
2 0.820181
3 0.811845
4 0.550399
5 0.811845
6 0.294830
7 0.557235
8 0.914733
9 0.557235
10 0.868979
11 0.206681
12 0.321921
13 0.206681
14 0.782857
15 0.539587
16 0.011302
17 0.539587
18 0.285450
19 0.739071
$
```

The kernel now causes each thread to generate 2 numbers in their sequence, but alternate threads will `skipahead_sequence` in between the generation of the 2 numbers.  Since I have chosen 1 as the first parameter to `skipahead_sequence`, the effect of the function call is as if I had asked for 1*2^67 numbers, i.e. as if I had done a call to `curand_uniform` 2^67 times. This means that pairs of threads will have their 2nd number generated be identical, and this is exactly what we see at indices 3 and 5, 7 and 9, 11 and 13, etc. in the output.

Here's some ASCII art:

Main Sequence (length 2^190)  (determined by `seed` parameter):

```
|0     ...   2^67-1 2^67 ...     2^68-1 2^68 ... ... ... 2^190|0 ... 
                                                              (main seq repeats)
```

Sequences     (each have length 2^67) (determined by `sequence` parameter):

```
|seq0  ...   2^67-1|seq1   ...   2^68-1|seq2   ... 
                           ^
                   |offset |                     (determined by offset parameter)
                           |
                           RNG begins here for given seed, sequence(=seq1), offset
```

Comment: +1 and accepted. Excellent answer, as always. Just to complete the picture to myself, which kind of RNG is invoked with a call to `curand_uniform`? Are the sequences `seq0, seq1, ...`, pseudo-random or quasi-random?

Comment: [the default generator type is pseudorandom numbers from XORWOW](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/curand/device-api-overview.html#quasirandom-sequences), and my description above (as well as the code you provided) has that generator in view.  The sequence mechanics can vary depending on the underlying generator, for example [mersenne twister](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/curand/device-api-overview.html#bit-generation-2) is quite a bit different.

Comment: I read your answer but i become a bit confused when i consider your answer and the result that @JackOLantern had seen. you said that "Within this overall sequence there are subsequences that are identified by the 2nd parameter of the curand_init call. These subsequences are independent from each other (and not statistically correlated)." so i expect that "curand_init(seed, idx, 2, &state);" be started from the third element of the Random Number Generator (RNG) sequence associated to seed = 1234 NOT "curand_init(seed, idx+2, 0, &state);" where am i wrong?